# Class 'Psr\Log\LogLevel' not found in ErrorHandler.php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

using `composer update` or `composer install` getting this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Psr\Log\LogLevel' not found in /var/www/html/Project/MRA/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php on line 121
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                             
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                      
  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Psr\Log\LogLevel' not found in /var/www/html/Project/MRA/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php on line  
   121                                                                                                                                                           
  .                                                                                                                                                              



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I'm using symfony 2.7.7 and here is my composer.json:

- "php": ">=5.3.9",
- "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
- "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
- "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
- "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
- "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
- "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
- "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
- "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
- "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
- "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
- "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
- "twbs/bootstrap": "^3.3",
- "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
- "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
- "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
- "craue/formflow-bundle": "~2.0",
- "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^1.7",
- "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*",
- "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.*",
- "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
- "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
- "siphoc/pdf-bundle": "1.2.*",
- "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.3",
- "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1"

Comment: `rm -rf app/cache/*` Agressive mode...

Comment: You should have a line like this: "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache", in your composer file. You can temporarily disable any of the postInstall scripts to get composer to finish and then manually debug why your autoloader isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, PSR Logger wasn't in the composer.json, so I added
`"psr/log": "dev-master"` into `composer.json` and fixed the error.
PS: don't know why suddenly it didn't work just because it wasn't installed!